# How to properly nest inside li tags in Jade

Tags: html, pug

This should be the simplest thing but for some reason I'm not getting what I expect. My template is dumb simple:

```
p The following user just signed up!
ul
  li= user.name
  li= user.email
  li  Sticker Code: #{user.code}
  li: p #{user.address_line1}
      if user.address_line2
        p #{user.address_line2}
      p #{user.address_city}, #{user.address_state} #{user.address_zip}
```

All I'm trying to do is have the address appear in ONE li tag, with an address line 2 if it exists. Instead, I'm getting a line break in front of the last li, and an empty line for address 2 when there is no address. I've tried about a million different variations, and aside from just writing the stinking HTML myself, I'm tired of just banging my head against the wall. I know this is simple as hell, so someone get some easy points so I can focus on more pressing issues.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an inspector in your web browser, you can see various properties of the DOM elements.  Included in those properties is margin.

The default in most browsers is for `p` tags to have margin above and below themselves.  This margin is what causes there to be a line break before the first line of the address.

I have reworked your template so it just uses line breaks instead of paragraph tags to have things on separate lines.  This makes more sense as the lines of an address are not actual paragraphs.

```
p The following user just signed up!
ul
  li= user.name
  li= user.email
  li  Sticker Code: #{user.code}
  li
    | #{user.address_line1}
    if user.address_line2
      br
      | #{user.address_line2}
    br
    | #{user.address_city}, #{user.address_state} #{user.address_zip}
```